# Promise behavior and printing order

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm a bit new to JavaScript and i can't figure out why the printing order of the following code is Noam and then Amit and only them.
can someone clarify it?

```js
function rc(){
   console.log('Assaf');
}

function thenCall(){
   console.log('Amit');
}

function myPromise(){
   return Promise.resolve(function(){
      console.log('Yarden');
      rc();
  });
}

myPromise().then(function(){thenCall()});
console.log('Noam');
```

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.resolve` takes a result which is passed to the `then`. It does not call the function. Notice the callback to `.then`.

```js
function rc(){
   console.log('Assaf');
}

function thenCall(){
   console.log('Amit');
}

function myPromise(){
   return Promise.resolve(function(){
      console.log('Yarden');
      rc();
  });
}

myPromise().then(function(fn){
   console.log(fn); // notice
   thenCall()
   
});
console.log('Noam');
```

Answer (score 1):

The function inside Promise.resolve should be executed as it will wait for a result to return:

```js
function rc(){
   console.log('Assaf');
}

function thenCall(){
   console.log('Amit');
}

function myPromise(){
   return Promise.resolve(function(){
      console.log('Yarden');
      rc();
  }());
}

myPromise().then(function(){thenCall()});
console.log('Noam');
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide the question by the people you're trying to log

### Noam

Noam is printed first, because there is no async process in the code. You do use a Promise but it instantly executes the resolve method.

### Amit

When `Promise.resolve` gets invoked, the function in the `.then` method will be executed. Therefore Amit gets printed in the console correctly.

### Yarden and Assaf

`Promise.resolve` immediately resolves a new Promise and calls therefore the `.then` method immediately. The argument given to `Promise.resolve` is the value that will be passed as an argument to the `.then` method.

To create an actual Promise that either resolves or rejects based on some logic, this should get you started:

```
var a = true;

function myPromise() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    console.log('first');

    if (a) {    
      return setTimeout(function () {
         resolve('value_to_pass_to_then');
      }, 1000);
    }

    return reject('value_to_pass_to_catch');
  });
}

myPromise()
  .then(function (val) { console.log('second'); })
  .catch(function (val) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Yarden` function is what the promise returned by `myPromise()` resolves to. But you aren't doing anything with the resolve value:

```
myPromise().then(function(/* resolve value would go here */){thenCall()});
```

The value a promise resolves to is the *first* argument of the function passed to `.then`. But you don't have an argument there. If you wanted to run that function, you would have to use it as an argument and then call it explicitly (which would in turn call the function that prints `Assaf`):

```js
function rc() {
  console.log('Assaf');
}

function thenCall() {
  console.log('Amit');
}

function myPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve(function() {
    console.log('Yarden');
    rc();
  });
}

myPromise().then(function(yardenFn) {
  thenCall();
  yardenFn();
});
console.log('Noam');
```